# upload azure blob using UploadFromStreamAsync Method

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

## Problem

I am trying to generate Pdf and create **MemoryStream** object and trying to upload that stream to azure Blob Storage. I am already tried the below code so far but the blob is not uploaded to azure and also what is the name of that blob which I upload using stream method of azure sdk

## Code

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
var cred = new StorageCredentials("foo", "key");
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("container");
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("foo/bar");
var attachment =  sourceBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream);
```

Comment: First thing that stands out is the missing `await` on the call to `UploadFromStreamAsync`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Kirk has said, use `await sourceBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream);` instead of `var attachment =  sourceBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream);` Or your code will exit before upload is finished.

Note that your method should change to `public async Task methodname()`, you will see related tip shown by VS.

Some references for you

- [Async and Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index#BKMK_AsyncandAwait)
- [How and when to use async and-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

And see `container.GetBlockBlobReference("blobname");` the string you use to get blob reference is the name of blob uploaded.